# How to get probability density functions (PDF) for an $N \times D$ matrix?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, density-function, python

Suppose we have an `N x D` matrix, as follows:

```
import numpy as np
X1 = np.matrix('1 2 3; 4 5 6;  0 0 -1, 0 0 -2')
```

I found an online example to compute pdf for each row of `X1` as follows:

```
from scipy import stats
PDFs = stats.norm.pdf(X1, loc=0.0, scale=1.0)
```

Above line of code gives a matrix of same size as `X1`, i.e., `N x D`. It appears that above line of code has computed **pdf** for each point of each sample row. However, I am not sure what it did and if it even makes any sense.

This is another online example which find probability mass function (**PMF**) for a single sample row list (I have an `N x D` data matrix):

```
tries = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] # 0 to 10
X2 = stats.binom.pmf(tries, 10, 0.5)
S = np.sum(X2, axis = 0)
```

I am looking for a way to find **pdfs** for each sample row of `N x D` data matrix so that output **pdfs** will be of the same size `N x D`. However, I am not sure if it will make any sense as a right representation of original data matrix? I could compute **KDE**, on the data, but that would give me an `N x 1` densities (i.e., equal to the number of sample size of evaluation matrix).

Does the output of $PDFs = stats.norm.pdf(X1, loc=0.0, scale=1.0)$ represent evaluated densities (pdfs) on each sample row? I am looking for a way to compute `N x D` matrix of densities. In KDE one first computes kde on some train dataset so that bandwidth can be optimized, and after that one can evaluate kde on any test dataset; the output is an `N x 1` array of densities. So I tried to evaluate densities by applying above scipy function which actually gave me a `N x D` matrix, but I am not sure what is it. Does it represent actual data?

Comment: The way numpy/scipy vectorise their functions is to return an array of the same shape as the input where each entry is the scalar valued function applied to that entry, so PDFs = stats.norm.pdf(X1, loc=0.0, scale=1.0) is just returning an array the same shape as $X1$ where each $i,j$th term is just $PDFs[i,j] = \exp(-0.5X1[i,j]^2)/(\sqrt{2\pi})$. You need to be more explicit about the joint pdfs of each row, if you do have an independence assumption then you can just apply a product along each row

Comment: @Nadiels I have added an extra paragraph explaining my question. Can you please elaborate your reply in answer?

Comment: still not clear exactly what you want, as I understand it you want to evaluate the probability of each row, which is fine, but what is the explicit form of that density, i.e. if a single row vector is $\mathbf{x}_i = x_{i1},x_{i2},\ldots,x_{iD}$ then that is the mathematical form of the density function $p(\mathbf{x}_i )$?

Comment: @Nadiels Yes, correct. So $p(x_{i})$ should be of a length grater than $1$, i.e., $p(x_{i}) = [p_{i1}, p_{i2},..., p_{iD}]$. So if $1 \leq I \leq N$, output densities should be a $N \times D$ matrix. Above line of code gives it, but I am not sure what it means and it if really represents actual data.